# Display an external web page in a width of 100px and height of 400px area

Tags: html, css

I wanted to display an external web page with a width of 100px and a height of 400px area. This is the code I wrote.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/exmo_frame.html" width="100" height="400">
      www.example.com/exmo_frame.html
    </a>
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

But I couldn't get the height and width as I wish. Can You help me to get the correct output?

Comment: This is a hyperlink. Try a iframe.

Comment: I believe you need to use an iframe tag. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), you can try the following:

```html
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.example.com/exmo_frame.html" style="height: 100px; width: 400px;" title="Example website"></iframe>
```